# Break loop based on element not existing

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, for-loop, getelementbyid

I have built a cms that allows users to add up to 10 images into the slideshow, which all output in the front end in divs with ids of showcaseSlide with a number from 0-9 appended on the end, e.g. showcaseSlide0, showcaseSlide1 etc. For the javascript that controls the slideshow, I need to output all of the div id's into an array, but end the array when the slides finish, eg if the div ids went from showcaseSlide0 - showcaseSlide3, I would need the array to go from slides[0] - slides[3].

Here is the current code and some commented out code that I have tried before:

```
var slides = new Array();
var count = 0;
for(i=0; i<=10; i++){
slides[i] = "showcaseSlide"+i;
document.write(slides[i]); //so that I can see which id's are in the array
var div = document.getElementById(slides[i]);
//if(div) { break; } <- doesn't break
//if(document.getElementById(slides[i]) == null) break; <-breaks after 1st
//if(document.getElementById(slides[i]) == undefined) break; <- breaks after 1st
};
```

**Edit:**

I've found out (thanks to Teemu who commented below) that it wasn't working because it was called before the page load, therefore before the objects were rendered. I also have to thank Peter Kelly (who also commented below), who pointed out that I needed to use a ! in my breaking if statement and Frazer who pointed out my loop was 1 too big.

Here is the new code (including the other elements of the initialising function):

```
var count = 0;
var wait = 4000;
var slides = [];

function startShowcase() {

    for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
        slides[i] = "showcaseSlide"+i;;
       if(!document.getElementById(slides[i])) { break; }
    };
    setInterval(showcase, wait);

};
```

Comment: have you tried if (!div)

Comment: *"breaks after 1st"*: Then the element with ID `showcaseSlide0` does not exist. The test itself is correct (although too verbose).

Comment: I have tried  if (!div) (breaks after the 1st) and document.getElementById(slides[count]) works in the function below which controls the slideshow (with count being a counter that resets when we reach the end of the array).

Comment: If this code is executed as a function call after page completed, remove `document.write`, it clears the document, including your script. Use `alert()` instead. If the code is executed while parsing the page, it is possible, that `showcaseSlide`-elements don't exist yet.

Comment: @Teemu that was exactly the problem. The document.write was working because the code was executing before the page body, therefore not being able to get the not-yet rendered divs. I have added it into my function that initialises the slideshow (which is called onload) and it now work :)

Comment: @Teemu: To hell with alert. Use the debugger and console.log instead.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be so complex. I guess you have a class applied to all your slides div? If you do, use something like the following:

```
var slides = []
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('slide-class')
for (var i = 0, l = divs.length; i < l; ++i) {
    slides.push("showcaseSlide" + i)
}
```

Btw, several comments about your code:

- Don't use `new Array()`. Instead, use `[]`. See [here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/array#more-on-array-definition) to understand why.
- You didn't use the `var` keyword to declare your `i` variable, which means this variable is global. Global is evil.
- `document.write` is evil.

I guess your `count` variable has some use later?

Comment: Note that `getElementsByClassName` is not available in IE8 and below.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine `document.write` is not evil, if you use it properly (to create a whole new document). It is incredible fast compared to DOM-manipulations. Obviously it's not suitable for OP's code.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers :). Yes, counter is the counter that controls which slide to apply effects to and when to reset to the beginning.

Comment: Indeed, `getElementsByClassName` is [not supported in IE8](http://caniuse.com/#search=getelementsbyclassname), but there are [some solutions](http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/) to use it cross-browser.

Answer (score 1):

You have DIVs numbered 0-9 but your loop runs 11 times.

Not actual code, but this explains it.

```
for(i=0; i<=10; i++){
  0 = 1st 
  1 = 2nd
  2 = 3rd
  3 = 4th
  4 = 5th
  5 = 6th
  6 = 7th
  7 = 8th
  8 = 9th
  9 = 10th
  10 = 11th
}
```